# Irreducibility of exterior powers of representations of the symmetric group over finite fields

Tags: representation-theory, finite-fields, symmetric-groups, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional standard representation of the symmetric group $S_n$ over the finite field of order $p.$

For which triples $(n,p,k)$ is $\bigwedge^k V$ irreducible? Or for a weaker version, for which pairs $(n,p)$ is $\bigwedge^k V$ irreducible for all $0\leq k \leq n-1$?

I know that Fulton-Harris answers this in characteristic 0, but I haven't found a reference for other fields.

Comment: This is not my field at all, but I found a question that mentions your authors, and seems related. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307120

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well a first observation is that if $p \vert n$ then the $n-1$ dimensional standard representation itself is not irreducible, and this will propagate to its exterior powers.

It turns out this is the only obstruction and that if $p \not\vert n$ then indeed these are indeed irreducible. One can probably prove this directly in this case, but I'll just appeal to a general theorem:

Carter's criterion (formulated in full by James and Mathas, with the last piece proved by Fayers) gives a combinatorial condition for which Specht modules $S^\lambda$ remain irreducible in characteristic $p$. I won't state it in full, but it involves looking at the $p$-valuations of the hook lengths. In the case of hook shape partitions the condition degenerates into just looking at whether $p$-divides the corner hook length or not.

Comment: The condition for the irreducibility of these representations in characteristic $p$ depends on both $k$ and $n$. The exterior power $\bigwedge^k$ is isomorphic to the Specht module $(−,1^)$. Carter's criterion applies only when the Specht module has simple head, which is when $(−,1^)$ is $$-regular. In which case the Carter criterion says that $\bigwedge^k$ is irreducible if and only if $$ *and* $!$ are nonzero mod . As Nate suggests, there is a similar condition when $(−,1^)$ is not $$-regular.